How to block outgoing SSH on an Ubuntu server?
I have a local Ubuntu server, I want a certain group to be able to SSH into the server but not out. What I mean by that is I want users to be able to connect to this server via SSH but if they try to SSH to any other systems on my network they will be blocked. I have tried iptables but nothing is happening.

What have you tried with iptables so far?

iptables is the correct tool if you want to disallow outgoing TCP to port 22 - this might be good enough or not. Its documentation will tell you, how to use it. Please understand that disallowing outgoing SSH to other ports comes with a lot of additional restrictions.

they try to ssh to any other systems on my network so where did even try iptables? On "themselves"? Or on a router "they" are connected to? Note that iptables on a router governs / filters only traffics from one interface (not necessarily the same thing as port) to another (could be the same one in certain cases), which would usually NOT be the case when the traffics go from one host to another that are within the same broadcast domain.

The basic way to do this in iptables is iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP, which blocks outbound ssh on port 22 for the whole system

The command would be run on the server they are SSH'ing from. No point putting it on the router as packets on the same segment ( on the LAN) don't traverse the router.
